# Exercise 1, Section 26 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, compactness, alternative-proof

> (a) Let $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}’$ be two topologies on the set $X$; suppose that $\mathcal{T}’ \supseteq \mathcal{T}$. What does compactness of $X$ under one of these topologies imply about compactness under the other?
>
> (b) Show that if $X$ is compact Hausdorff under both $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}’$, then either $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}’$ are equal or they are not comparable.

**My attempt:**

**(a)** Rephrase this problem. **Claim:** If $X$ is equipped with $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}’$ topology, $Y\subseteq X$ is compact in $(X,\mathcal{T}’)$ and $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}’$, then $Y$ is compact in $(X,\mathcal{T})$. **Proof:** let $U=\{ U_\alpha \in \mathcal{T}|\alpha \in J\}$ be an open cover of $Y$ in $(X,\mathcal{T})$. Since $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}’$ and $Y$ is compact in $(X,\mathcal{T}’)$, $\exists \{ U_{\alpha_1},..,U_{\alpha_n}\}$ finite subcover of $U$. Hence $Y$ is compact in $(X,\mathcal{T})$.

**(b)** **Approach(1):** If $\mathcal{T}= \mathcal{T}’$, then we are done. If $\mathcal{T} \nsubseteq \mathcal{T}’$ and $\mathcal{T} \nsupseteq \mathcal{T}’$ i.e. $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}’$ are not comparable, then we are done. Now assume $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}’$. Let $U\in \mathcal{T}’$. Then $X-U$ is closed in $(X, \mathcal{T}’ )$. By theorem 26.2, $X-U$ is compact in $(X, \mathcal{T}’ )$. By exercise 1(a) section 26, $X-U$ is compact in $(X, \mathcal{T})$. By theorem 26.3, $X-U$ is closed in $(X, \mathcal{T})$. Thus $U\in \mathcal{T}$. So $\mathcal{T}’ \subseteq \mathcal{T}$. Hence $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}’$. Therefore $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}’$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}’$. Similarly if $\mathcal{T}’ \subseteq \mathcal{T}$, then $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}’$. **Is this proof correct?** https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2975675/861687 above proof is “complete”. **Note:** In proof of $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}’$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}’$, we didn’t make use of fact $(X, \mathcal{T}’)$ is Hausdorff and $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is compact. Said differently, in proof of $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}’$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}’$, we only use the fact $(X, \mathcal{T}’)$ is compact and $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is Hausdorff.

**Approach(2):** https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2442182/861687. $f:(X,\mathcal{T}’) \to (X,\mathcal{T})$ defined by $f(x)=x$, i.e. $f$ is identity map. Let $V\in \mathcal{T}$. It’s easy to check $f^{-1}(V)=V$. By assumption, $ f^{-1}(V)=V \in \mathcal{T}\subseteq \mathcal{T}’$. Thus $f^{-1}(V)\in \mathcal{T}’$. Hence $f$ is continuous. Proof of homeomorphism is in theorem 26.6. So $f^{-1}=g: (X,\mathcal{T})\to (X, \mathcal{T}’)$ is continuous. Let $U\in \mathcal{T}’$. It’s easy to check $g^{-1}(U)=U$. So $g^{-1}(U)=U \in \mathcal{T}$, since $g$ is continuous. Thus $\mathcal{T}’ \subseteq \mathcal{T}$. $ \mathcal{T}’ = \mathcal{T}$. Our desired result.

Comment: yes, the first two proofs work. Probably the third does as well, but while I can figure out what the earlier theorems you reference must be from the context, I am too rusty to be sure exactly what theorem 26.6 must be, so I cannot say for sure that you are applying it correctly. Your opening 2 sentences for (b) are correct, but pointless. It is sufficient to prove that if $\cal T \subseteq T'$, then $\cal T = T'$. Applying that result to $\cal T' \subseteq T$ as well gives that the two being comparable implies they have to be equal. And conversely, being equal is being comparable,

Comment: And it is because you need both $\cal T \subseteq T'$ and $\cal T' \subseteq T$ to imply $\cal T = T'$ that $\cal T$ and $\cal T'$ each need to be both compact and Hausdorff.